# Mapear en modelo dos campos primera key

Tags: c#

Tengo una tabla cuya estructura esta compuesta por dos PK, quiero incluirla en mi modelo para insertar registros a la misma, pero presento problemas al realizar esto
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

mi duda es como declaro en mi modelo que tengo esos dos campos como pk, he intentado de esa forma pero arroja error

```
namespace MvcApp.Models
{
    public class credito_por_factura
    {
        [Key]
        public decimal id_factura { get; set; }
        [Key]
        public decimal id_credito { get; set; }
    }
}
```

> ERROR: No se puede determinar el orden de clave principal compuesta para el tipo 'MvcApp.Models.credito_por_factura'. Use el método HasKey o ColumnAttribute para especificar el orden de las claves principales compuestas.

NOTA: estoy trabajando sobre el código de otro programador y no entiendo por que definió esa estructura, yo lo haría de otra forma pero no puedo alterar la estructura de las tablas

Comment: Prueba con `[Key, Column(Order=1)]` y `[Key, Column(Order=2)]`

Comment: estas usando entity framework ? porque defines los campos key como decimal, eso no esta bueno, los id son int

Comment: para algunos casos EF y para otros EDM, leandro es la estructura que definió el otro programador y al parecer se define así por que las tablas tienen más de 1 millón de registros

Comment: pero si revisas los tipos de datos https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/int-bigint-smallint-and-tinyint-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017&viewFallbackFrom=sql-server-2014   un tipo de dato int soporta mas de un millon de registros y sino tienes el bigint, no se los conocimientos de ese "otro programador" pero recomendaria estudiar un poco mas

Comment: @LeandroTuttini gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para crear una Primary Key compuesta en EF, debes indicar el orden de cada columna usando la anotación `Column`.

De la documentación:

> Entity Framework admite las claves compuestas - claves principales que constan de más de una propiedad. Por ejemplo, podría tener una clase de Passport cuya clave principal es una combinación de PassportNumber y IssuingCountry.
>
> Para poder usar las claves compuestas, Entity Framework requiere que definen el orden de las propiedades de clave. Puede hacerlo mediante la anotación de columna para especificar un orden:

```
public class Passport
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order=1)]
    public int PassportNumber { get; set; }
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 2)]
    public string IssuingCountry { get; set; }
    public DateTime Issued { get; set; }
    public DateTime Expires { get; set; }
}
```

*Enlace: [Anotaciones de datos de Code First](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/data-annotations#composite-keys)*

Comment: ha desaparecido el error, ahora me arroja este `{"El nombre de objeto 'dbo.credito_por_factura1' no es válido."} `

Comment: @Andrex_11 eso ya sería para otra pregunta, pero tiene toda la pinta de que no existe esa tabla en tu base de datos....Revisa la base de datos y la cadena de conexión, por si son incorrectas

Comment: tienes razón, @pikoh sería otra pregunta. Claro que existe, es la misma tabla de la que estamos hablando y tiene el mismo nombre del modelo

Comment: @Andrex_11,si existe, revisa la cadena de conexión a ver si se está conectando a la base de datos correcta. Pero fijate en en el error, esta buscando `dbo.credito_por_factura1` (terminado en 1) y tu clase es `credito_por_factura`

Comment: revise la conexion y es correcta, tambien valide el nombre del modelo y esta bien, ahora no se de donde me tomo ese objeto, claro `dbo.credito_por_factura1` no existe en la base de datos